# Is it possible that very small particles disappear as I use RTT?

Tags: macos, opengl, render-to-texture

I have developed more than 20 mobile apps using OpenGL ES 2.0. However, I am trying to make a renderer to use my apps in OSX so now I am using OpenGL v3.3 with GLSL v130. Yesterday, I ran into a problem that I can't use a texture(RTT) that I drew particles on Off-Screen FBO with GL_LINES 1.0 size (it is the max value in OpenGL 3.3 why??)

When I drew geometry on the Off Screen FBO and used it as a texture on On-screen, I was able to see that 
and also if I draw small particles on On-screen I can clearly see those but if I try to draw that particle lines and try to use it as a texture on Main screen I can see only a black texture.

I have already checked GL ERRORs and back FBOs' status and GL blending options but I am still struggling to solve it .

Anyone has a idea to solve it ?

Even though I think my code is okay I attached a little code bellow

```
// AFTER generate and bind FBO, generate RTT 
StarTexture fboTex;
fboTex.texture_width = texture_width;
fboTex.texture_height = texture_height;
glGenTextures(1, &fboTex.texture_id);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,fboTex.texture_id);

glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texture_width, texture_height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboTex.texture_id, 0);
```

and this is drawing particles on BACK FBO

```
glUniformMatrix4fv( h_Uniforms[UNIFORMS_PROJECTION], 1, GL_FALSE, g_proxtrans.s);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, h_VBO[VBO_PARTICLE]);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(Vec3)*ParticleNumTotal*2, &p_particle_lc_xy[0]);
glVertexAttribPointer(h_Attributes[ATTRIBUTES_POSITION], 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0,0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(h_Attributes[ATTRIBUTES_POSITION]);


glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, h_VBO[VBO_COLOR]);
glVertexAttribPointer(h_Attributes[ATTRIBUTES_COLOR], 4, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0,0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(h_Attributes[ATTRIBUTES_COLOR]);

glLineWidth(Thickness); // 1.0 because it is maxium

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, h_VBO[VBO_INDEX_OFF1]);
glDrawElements(GL_LINES, 400, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0); // 200 lines
```

and when I draw that on the main screen

```
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

starfbo->bindingVAO1();

glViewport(0, 0, ogl_Width, ogl_Height);
glUseProgram(h_Shader_Program[Shader_Program_FINAL]);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, h_VBO[VBO_TEXCOORD2]);
glVertexAttribPointer(h_Attributes[ATTRIBUTES_UV2], 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0,0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(h_Attributes[ATTRIBUTES_UV2]);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, h_VBO[VBO_SQCOORD2]);
glVertexAttribPointer(h_Attributes[ATTRIBUTES_POSITION3], 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0,0 );
glEnableVertexAttribArray(h_Attributes[ATTRIBUTES_POSITION3]);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, h_VBO[VBO_INDEX_ON]);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,sizeof(squareIndices)/sizeof(squareIndices[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_INT ,(void*)0);

  glUniformMatrix4fv( h_Uniforms[UNIFORMS_PROJECTION], 1, GL_FALSE, g_proxtrans.s);


glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, h_VBO[VBO_PARTICLE]);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(Vec3)*ParticleNumTotal*2, &p_particle_lc_xy[0]);
glVertexAttribPointer(h_Attributes[ATTRIBUTES_POSITION], 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0,0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(h_Attributes[ATTRIBUTES_POSITION]);


glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, h_VBO[VBO_COLOR]);
glVertexAttribPointer(h_Attributes[ATTRIBUTES_COLOR], 4, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0,0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(h_Attributes[ATTRIBUTES_COLOR]);

glLineWidth(Thickness);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, h_VBO[VBO_INDEX_OFF1]);
glDrawElements(GL_LINES, 400, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

Comment: As an experiment, you could try clearing the FBO with something other than black. That would show you if the texture is successfully used as the render target, and if sampling from it during your second render pass works.

Comment: @Reto Koradi As I told you, the FBO is successfully used but particles disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
glDrawElements(GL_LINES, 400, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

GL_UNSIGNED_INT can not be used in OpenGL ES Versus OpenGL. Oddly, it works for IOS but not Android.

The parameter must be **GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE** or **GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT** in OpenGL ES.

Answer (score 2):

If the resolution of the rendered image is much larger than the size (in pixels) it ends up being rendered at, it's certainly possible that small features disappear entirely.

Picture an extreme case. Say you render a few thin lines into a 1000x1000 texture, lighting up a very small fraction of the total 1,000,000 pixels. Now you map this texture onto a quad that has a size of 10x10 pixels when displayed. The fragment shader is invoked once for each pixel (assuming no MSAA), which makes for 100 shader invocations. Each of these 100 invocations samples the texture. With linear sampling and no mipmapping, it will read 4 texels for each sample operation. In total, 100 * 4 = 400 texels are read while rendering the polygon. It's quite likely that reading these 400 texels out of the total 1,000,000 will completely miss all of the lines you rendered into the texture.

One way to reduce this problem is to use mipmapping. This will generally prevent the features from disappearing completely. But small features will still fade because more and more texels are averaged in higher mipmap levels, where most of the texels are black.

A better but slightly more complex approach is that instead of using automatically generated mipmaps, you create the mipmaps manually, by rendering the same content into each mipmap level.

It might be good enough to simply be careful that you're not making the texture too large. Or to create your own wide lines by drawing them as polygons instead of using line primitives.